# Redirecionar de Http para Https no ExternalLogin do Owin + OAuth + Google

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

No Host onde minha aplicação está hospedada utiliza o ARR para redirecionar todas as páginas para `Https`.

O problema é que da forma que está configurado o código do `asp.net mvc` entende que a requisição é `http`, mesmo sendo `https`.

Quando eu vejo a URL que vai para a autenticação do Google está assim:

```
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%mydomain.com\signing-google
```

Então estou tentando redirecionar para o Google alterando "na mão" para `https`.

Já tentei isso:

```
 public class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
{
   ...

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
        if (UserId != null)
            properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;

        var owin = context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext();

        owin.Request.Scheme = "https"; //hotfix

        owin.Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
    }
}
```

e isso:

```
 app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = Secrets.GoogleClientId,
                ClientSecret = Secrets.GoogleClientSecret,
                Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
                {
                    OnApplyRedirect = async context =>
                    {
                        string redirect = context.RedirectUri;

                        redirect = redirect.Replace("redirect_uri=http", "redirect_uri=https");
                        context.Response.Redirect(redirect);
                    }
                }
            });
```

As duas formas funcionam e o Google consegue redirecionar para minha aplicação novamente, porém no momento que vou pegar os dados do usuário ele retornar `null`.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            returnUrl = "~/";

        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            //sempre retorna null se eu mudo de http para https "na mão"
        }
```

Eu tentei ver a implementação do método `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()`, mas não encontrei o porque de sempre retornar `null` quando faço esse *workaround*.

Comment: Ja tentou alguma das solucoes dada nesta [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775321/owins-getexternallogininfoasync-always-returns-null/29921451#29921451)?(nota: link para o SOEN)

Comment: Já resolveu alguma coisa?

Comment: No meu caso, a única solução foi falar com o setor de infra e alterar a configuração do ARR. Então não sei o que fazer com esta pergunta (visto que não teve uma solução).

Answer (score 1):

Isto não deve ser resolvido por código. Isto deve ser resolvido por configuração do IIS.

A melhor forma é inserindo no seu `Web.config` o seguinte:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    ...
  </system.webServer>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Nos meus sistemas, normalmente coloco esta parte no arquivo de transformação (`Web.Release.config`):

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    ...
  </system.webServer>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes ajuntar um codigo JavaScript a tua pagin html no head:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 function redirectHttpToHttps()
 {
    var httpURL= window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname +    window.location.search;
    var httpsURL= "https://" + httpURL;
    window.location = httpsURL;
 }
 redirectHttpToHttps();
</script>
```

Comment: Mas acho que isso é melhor configurar no ISS como disse o Cigano Morrison Mendez